# JTA for single database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, transactions, jta

I am just learning JTA and can't understand if I should use it if I have only one database. Currently I use hibernate 5 as JPA provider and if I need to use one transaction between methods I just pass EntityManager as argument.

However, I don't like this method as I need to remember if transaction is opened or not. I would like to find any library that will help me to control transactions (but without Spring) in SE environment. So, should I use JTA in my situation or should I use something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally when talking about JTA , it refers to the distributed transaction across multiple systems (e.g. across two databases , one database and one JMS compliant message broker). If you only have one database , it is not necessary to use JTA transaction although it should also work. Instead, use a local transaction for one database which should theoretically faster than using JTA transaction.

On the other hands , if you are just talking about `@Transactional` defined in the JTA , which allow you to declaratively control the transaction boundary by annotating it on a method and without passing the EntityManager between methods , you should look into which frameworks support it.

Under the cover , a proxied EntityManager is injected into different classes such that when it is invoked , it will get the actual EntityManager from the ThreadLocal. So every class in the same thread will get the same EntityManager which prevent you from passing the EntityManager around the methods. A new EntityManager instance will be set to the ThreadLocal just before the  `@Transactional` method is executed using some sort of AOP technique.

Please note that `@Transcational` is nothing to do with the underlying transaction is JTA or local transaction. It should work for both transaction type.

I would use a framework that support `@Transactional` such as Spring , [`Quarkus`](https://quarkus.io/guides/transaction) or [`Micronaut`](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/index.html#transactions) etc , and configure Hibernate to use local transaction but not JTA transaction for single database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you say, if there is a library for managing transactions outside frameworks?

Comment: I am not aware of it . If you try to do it your own , you are most probably will find that you are re-inventing the wheel at the end. It is not simple to do that . Under the cover , it requires to inject a proxied `EntityManger ` into different classes such that when a proxied EntityManager is invoked , it will get the actual EntityManger from the ThreadLocal to ensure every classes in the same thread get the same `EntityManager`. The `EntityManger` will be set to the ThreadLocal in the beginning of the `@Tranasactional` method using some AOP magic.

Comment: @Yes, I also think that EntityManager must be bind to ThreadLocal that's why I asked about library.